# How do I get to the sub-element of the elements found with FindElement Xpath in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use driver.find_elements. I can access texts with my code, but not img. How can I access everything inside the div.

[image]

I used this, but not working

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=windows_path, chrome_options=op)
driver.get("http://tiktok.com/@"+username+"/live")

while True:
    
    gifts = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="tiktok-rpgkhd"]')
    for gift in gifts:
        
        try:
            c = str(gift.text)   
            img = gift.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//img")
        except:
            continue
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks..!!

Comment: Do you mean you are getting here non-empty text string `c` while `img` is an empty list?

Comment: img = gift.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//img") when I don't write this code, the text in span comes to c. But I also want to get the src of the img

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTML block you showing in the question, `gift` element contains a block of inner elements. So, `gift.text` will give you all the text inside this block.
In order to get the `src` attribute value of the `img` element you have to use `find_element` method, not the `find_elements` method. Then you will be able to retrieve the `src` attribute value with `get_attribute` method.
Also, you are missing delays here. After opening the page with `driver.get("http://tiktok.com/@"+username+"/live")` you should give a time to make elements loaded on the page before you are going to access them. As following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=windows_path, chrome_options=op)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("http://tiktok.com/@"+username+"/live")

while True:
    gifts = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="tiktok-rpgkhd"]')))
    for gift in gifts:
        try:
            c = str(gift.text)   
            img_el = gift.find_element(By.XPATH,".//img")
            src_val = img_el.get_attribute("src)
        except:
            continue
```

Also, your `while` loop here is missing an exit point. I mean it's an endless loop...

Comment: I used time.sleep(5). When the live ends, the while loop ends. Thank you so much . find_element methot is working. I did't notice it

Comment: Ah, I understand. In case this helped / resolved your issue please accept the answer